# Factor Levels in Interaction Terms for GLM

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, interaction

I have not been able to find an answer to this in other discussions or in my readings.

Say I am modeling `carVal` (i.e., a car's value) based on `mpg` (numeric variable) and `type` (factor variable with levels 0 = sedan, 1 = van, 2 = truck, 3 = suv) using a `glm()`. I have read that if I am using some algorithm to select the "best" model features, it is not appropriate to drop some of the factor variables but keep the others (i.e., `carVal ~ mpg + type1` is not valid, it would have to be `carVal ~ mpg + type1 + type2 + type3`).

My question is, if I include an interaction term between `mpg` and `type`, is it appropriate to have an interaction for only certain levels of `mpg` and `type`, but not include all levels of `type` for the interaction.

For example, is this a valid model:

```
carVal ~ mpg + type1 + type2 + type3 + type1:mpg
```

Or, would the formula have to be the following:

```
carVal ~ mpg + type1 + type2 + type3 + type1:mpg + type2:mpg + type3:mpg
```

Here is an example of the code I am using in version 4.0.2 of R:

```
library(leaps)

carVal = c(1000, 15000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 5000, 8000, 9500, 11000)  
mpg = c(29, 45, 20, 28, 30, 40, 35, 38, 47)  
type = as.factor(c(1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0))  
car.data = data.frame(carVal, mpg, type)  
subset.model = regsubsets(x = as.formula('carVal ~ mpg + type + type:mpg'), data = car.data, method = 'exhaustive')

summary(subset.model)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I would avoid any stepwise procedures.

That said:

> if I include an interaction term between mpg and type, is it appropriate to have an interaction for only certain levels of type and mpg, but not include all levels of type for the interaction.

Normally you would just specify the model as

```
carVal ~ mpg * type
```

or equivalently:

```
carVal ~ mpg + type + mpg:type
```

Then the software will create all the necessary dummy variables and interactions between them and `mpg`

It looks from your question that you might be creating the dummy variables yourself, in which case there is no technical reason why you can't omit some of the interactions, if you have good reason to, but in my experience this can create all kinds of problems such as a rank-deficient model matrix, or an overfitted model which generalises extremely poorly to new data.

So if you want to interaction, just use `mpg * type` - it will make your life much easier.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  I am not creating dummy variables myself, but the functions i am using for feature selection (regsubsets, bestglm, gglasso) do binarize the data, and the models/subsets tend to partially exclude factor levels.  I included sample code in my post with regsubsets.

Comment: Don't use those functions. Use knowledge.